# PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

Tenho um servidor com um servlet + um banco em postgreSQL. Eu gostaria que só o servlet conectasse no banco.

Quando eu configuro o pg_hba.conf com **local all all        md5** o servlet não consegue conectar no banco. Aí preciso configurar como **host all all  127.0.0.1   255.255.255.255   md5**

Com esta segunda configuração estou deixando o postgreSQL aberto para qualquer IP externo?

Comment: Não está dando erro, a minha dúvida é se o servidor está ficando aberto para para qualquer conexão externa.

Comment: Ah bom desculpa, entendi errado

Comment: De qualquer forma agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Para ficar aberto para qualquer maquina deve colocar

```
host    all             all             0/0             md5
```

assim libera para qualquer maquina

Answer (score 0):

Configurar

**host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5**

**host** "*todos os bancos*" "*todos os usuários*" "*localhost*" "*com senha*"

Assim o banco só pode ser acessado como localhost.